# Reading multiple raster/netCDF data in R slows down after a few iterations

Tags: r, r-raster, netcdf4

I have 9000+ netCDF files I am extracting data from at points. The bottleneck is reading in the data to raster::bricks (or stacks).

The netCDF have only 1 time step (single day), but have 72 layers for elevation and 84 variables. I am extracting data for each day, for each variable, and the 72nd layer.

My approach is to use raster::brick followed by extract(). I make use of lapply (or purrr::map, no big difference here). My problem is that after a few iterations the reading in the data gets much much slower. Initially, one variable to read in takes ~0.25 seconds, but then it slows down to ~6 seconds. The raster bricks themselves are not being saved at each iteration - there is nothing else that SHOULD be growing, so I'm at a loss. I'm on a Mac, R402. TIA!

https://portal.nccs.nasa.gov/datashare/merra2_gmi/

Example code: I simply put the print(x) to keep track, but would eventually remove once the issue is resolved.

```
z <- lapply(1:length(varnames), 
    function(x) { 
         print(x)
         raster::brick(MERRA2.GMI.filenames.read[i],varname = varnames[x])[[72]] 
         %>% crop(US.extent)
     }
   ) 
%>% raster::brick()
```

Comment: If I understand the code sample, you are generating a list with 9000 rasters. How big are the rasters? Potentially the slowness is caused by the internals of how lapply dynamically expands the list, but hard to tell

Comment: So, I was initially creating the large of rasters, which would then feed into the next lapply/map function. However, I've opted to do everything in 1 function in the hopes that the each iteration just overrides the raster.

Comment: Here is some more code:
```
    assign.fun <- function(i) {
  print(i)

  
  z <- lapply(1:length(varnames),function(x){print(x); 
    raster::brick(MERRA2.GMI.filenames.read[i],varname = varnames[x])[[72]] %>% 
      crop(US.extent) }) %>% raster::brick()
  
  # Get the time index
  idx <- monitor.merra.vars$Days == monitor.locs.j[[i]]$Days[1]
  # get the locations
  locs <- monitor.locs.j[[i]][,1:2] %>% SpatialPoints()
  val <- raster::extract(z,locs)
  monitor.merra.vars[idx,5:88] <<- val
}

val <- lapply(1:15,assign.fun)
```

Comment: Is this true? "The raster bricks themselves are not being saved at each iteration". Is the piping chain in your post evaluated lazily? (I suspect it's not, though some tidyverse methods can work lazily with piping). If not you are adding a raster to RAM each iteration

Comment: The raster brick is being saved, but it is not the output of the overall function. So, from my understanding, multiple raster bricks should not be loaded in as the i-th brick overrides the ith. However, perhaps there is something going on behind the scenes that keeps that information.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide is not entirely clear. Presumably `i` is the day (one of the 9000)? Then the `lapply` puts a RasterBrick of `US.extent` in list `z` for all  varnames. These layers are then piped into raster::brick. I assume that after that you extract values for the points of interest and then loop to the next day?

In that case you are saving RasterBricks for two days (168 some layers) of data at most (up to just before the data for a day overwrites the previous day; assuming that unused memory is freed immediately).

The below might perform better. The call to `brick` after the `lapply` is more expensive than the call to `stack`, as the latter does not actually read any values yet, it only points at the files. It should (but you never know) also be faster to only use `crop` once; and by doing so you do not create a list with raster data in memory (only references to files, until `crop` is called).

```
z <- lapply(1:length(varnames), 
    function(x) { 
         raster::brick(filenames[i], varname = varnames[x])[[72]] 
     }
   ) 
 s <- stack(z) %>% crop(US.extent)
```

I downloaded one file and I would suggest the following workflow, using `terra`  which is generally faster, especially if you are extracting with polygons. But in this case, `terra` also makes it easier to select the variables of interest, avoiding the `lapply` entirely.

For one file, I create a SpatRasterDataSet to understand the subdataset structure

```
library(terra)
f <- "MERRA2_GMI.inst0_3d_ovp_Nv.19900202_1200z.nc4"
s <- sds(f)
s
#class       : SpatRasterDataset 
#subdatasets : 74 
#dimensions  : 361, 576 (nrow, ncol)
#nlyr        : 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, ... 
#resolution  : 0.625, 0.5  (x, y)
#extent      : -180.3125, 179.6875, -90.25, 90.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. :  
#source(s)   : MERRA2_GMI.inst0_3d_ovp_Nv.19900202_1200z.nc4 
#names       : OVP10_AGE, OVP10_CH2O, OVP10_CH4, OVP10_CO, OVP10_EM_LGTNO, OVP10_EPV, OVP10_FCLD, OVP10_GOCART_SO2_VMR, OVP10_GOCART_SO2v_VMR, OVP10_NO, OVP10_NO2, OVP10_O3, OVP10_PL, OVP10_PPBL, OVP10_PS, OVP10_QLTOT, OVP10_QV_VMR, OVP10_T, OVP10_TAUTT, OVP10_TOTEXTTAU, OVP10_TROPP, OVP10_U10, OVP10_V10, OVP10_stO3, OVP14_AGE, OVP14_Br, OVP14_BrCl, OVP14_BrO, OVP14_BrONO2, OVP14_CH2O, OVP14_CH3Cl, OVP14_CH4, OVP14_CO, OVP14_Cl, OVP14_Cl2, OVP14_Cl2O2, OVP14_ClO, OVP14_ClONO2, OVP14_EM_LGTNO, OVP14_EPV, OVP14_FCLD, OVP14_GOCART_NH3_VMR, OVP14_GOCART_SO2_VMR, OVP14_GOCART_SO2v_VMR, OVP14_HBr, OVP14_HCOOH, OVP14_HCl, OVP14_HNO3, OVP14_HNO3COND, OVP14_HO2, OVP14_HOBr, OVP14_HOCl, OVP14_ISOP, OVP14_MOH, OVP14_N2O, OVP14_NO, OVP14_NO2, OVP14_O3, OVP14_OClO, OVP14_OH, OVP14_PAN, OVP14_PL, OVP14_PPBL, OVP14_PS, OVP14_QLTOT, OVP14_QV_VMR, OVP14_R4N2, OVP14_T, OVP14_TAUTT, OVP14_TOTEXTTAU, OVP14_TROPP, OVP14_U10, OVP14_V10, OVP14_stO3
```

Select the layers of interest. Some variables only have one layer, so I am taking  the 72th layer for those variables that have that many.

```
n <- nlyr(s)
i <- cumsum(n)
i <- i[n==72]
```

Or you could do the below, note that `rast(f)` combines all subdatasets into one multi-layer dataset

```
r <- rast(f)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 361, 576, 4334  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.625, 0.5  (x, y)
#extent      : -180.3125, 179.6875, -90.25, 90.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. :  
#sources     : MERRA2_GMI.inst0_3d_ovp_Nv.19900202_1200z.nc4:OVP10_AGE  (72 layers) 
#              MERRA2_GMI.inst0_3d_ovp_Nv.19900202_1200z.nc4:OVP10_CH2O  (72 layers) 
#              MERRA2_GMI.inst0_3d_ovp_Nv.19900202_1200z.nc4:OVP10_CH4  (72 layers) 
#              ... and 71 more source(s)
#varnames    : OVP10_AGE (Age of air (uniform source) tracer_10am_local) 
#              OVP10_CH2O (Formaldehyde_10am_local) 
#              OVP10_CH4 (Methane_10am_local) 
#              ...
#names       : OVP10~lev=1, OVP10~lev=2, OVP10~lev=3, OVP10~lev=4, OVP10~lev=5, OVP10~lev=6, ... 
#unit        :        days,        days,        days,        days,        days,        days, ... 
#time        : 0 
 
i <- grep("lev=72", names(r))
head(i)
#[1]  72 144 216 288 360 432
```

Now in a loop (lapply if you prefer) over filenames, create a SpatRaster, subset with `i`, and use `extract`

```
r <- rast(f)[[i]]
extract(r, v)
```

where `v` is a SpatVector.

Comment: The subtleties of the raster/brick/stack are tricky. I've also looked at terra a bit but will try out your suggestions. Thank you and I will let you know if it provides a reasonable solution.